# MVC access application settings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am not sure how to use my application settings in my mvc4 application.
For example I have an setting (stored in db), wether to use logging or not.

Should I load the setting once at application startup and then store it in the session-variable and check it against that? Or should I everytime i invoke an actionresult load the setting from database?

Whats the best practise here?

Comment: Is this setting get changed frequently ?

Comment: If you store the setting in the Web.config then any time you change that file the application should re-load the setting(s).  So just pulling directly from configuration data on each call should work just fine.

Comment: then go with my answer below

Answer (score 9):

You can keep this setting in web.config file:

```
 <appSettings>
        <add key="enableLogging" value="false"/>
 </appSettings>
```

And access it like this (requires reference to System.Configuration assembly):

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["enableLogging"];
```

Note that this stores only string values, so you could parse it or just compare against string.

Comment: Can I write the appsetting as well to the configurationmanager? I want to bo able to edit the setting in forms

Comment: Yes you can. But when you change web.config (as in saving new value), your website will restart itself. Not a good thing. So in your case this is not the best solution then. :(

Answer (score 4):

in this case store it in :

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache
```

storing it there will be available to all the requests  and set the expire to 24 hours for example

this is not permanent storage , so whenever it expire you need to read it from DB

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted - the value should be loaded from the DB into the application cache with a cache dependency that times out after a while so as to periodically refresh the value from the DB